# import .of() for Observable in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

I'm using this great repo for my angular 2 test project (TypeScript) - https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter. And I need to use **Observable.of(..)**. When I try to import it:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

I get:

> > Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

I also tried it the following way:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { of } from 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; // notice 'add'
```

I got:

> > node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/of"' has no exported member 'of'.

So, how can one import this Of() static method for Observable???

Comment: Note that it actually shows you how to do this in the repo: https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter/blob/7bb0754bae7526938c7df2f2e79e94511131c7de/src/rxjs.imports.ts

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<strike>You do not have to import `{of}` from `'rxjs/add/observable/of'`. You can directly use</strike>

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
```

<strike>Or you can import `Observable` from "rxjs/Rx" which bundle all the operators.</strike> *Bad practice*

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
```

### Update 2018-01-26: RxJS v5.5+ pipeable operators

From https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

> Starting in version 5.5 we have shipped "pipeable operators", which can be accessed in rxjs/operators (notice the pluralized "operators"). These are meant to be a better approach for pulling in just the operators you need than the "patch" operators found in rxjs/add/operator/*.

Now that "patching" imports are going to be deprecated, it would be better to use strict imports.

```
import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs/observable/of'
```

and use it like that

```
const myObs$: Observable<number> = observableOf(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What is the correct way of importing 'of' or 'from' after pipeable operators have been introduced?

Comment: Pipeable operator does not concern create function, like of, from, combineLatest, etc. You can import of like I do in the example above.

Comment: Getting cute'sy with the strikethrough font makes this "answer" confusing

Answer (score 22):

### RxJS 6

Starting with *RxJS 6*, the imports were greatly simplified and cause less confusion now thanks to a more **intuitive API surface**:

1. Creation methods like **`of`** are directly imported from `'rxjs'`:

   `import { of } from 'rxjs';`
2. All pipeable **operators** are imported from `'rxjs/operators'`, e.g.:

   `import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

---

### Migration:

If you're updating directly from RxJS 5, you can even utilize the TSLint rules for RxJS, which will automatically fix your imports to the newer, simplified API:

1. `npm i -g rxjs-tslint`
2. `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p [path/to/tsconfig.json]`

Comment: import { of } from 'rxjs'; It worked for me. Thanks!!