# Importing rxjs modules the right way

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I want to import `of` from `rxjs` on my Angular 8.2.3 project.
However, I see that this is present in 2 locations -

`import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

`import { of } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of';`

Which way do I go?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579452/import-of-for-observable-in-typescript

Comment: See: [RxJS Import paths](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#import-paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to say, you can use directly:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Else, you have to use

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```